# How to reinstall and locate it in /usr/local/bin/protoc

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, protocol-buffers

I am using protoc version 2.5.0. However, I have deleted it by the command

rm `which protoc`

I think it deleted the  `/usr/local/bin/protoc` directory. I tried to reinstall it by

```
sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler
```

However, I could not recreate the above folder. All of my source code run with the protobuf compiler often shows the error

> error while loading shared libraries: libprotobuf.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please help me to fix it

Answer (score -2):

I think your installation/explanation is quite wrong.

- apt-get typically doesn't install to /usr/local. It usually installs to /usr. You probably installed from source if you had /usr/local.
- libprotobuf.so.12 is for protobuf 3.2.0, not 2.5.0.

I suggest to `apt-get remove protobuf*` and clean-install from source with `--prefix=/usr` if you want.